# get list items in sharePoint 2013 for google charts api

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server, spservices

I'm trying to use Google Chart API in SharePoint 2013.

My list name is `Utilization` and I want to retrieve columns `Title` and `Portal` for making the 3D pie chart.

Here is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart); 
     var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();  
    data.addColumn('string', 'Resource'); 
        data.addColumn('number', 'Portal');  
             function  GetMyData() {
          $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "utilization",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='portal' /><FieldRef Name='content' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
          var listtitle=$(this).attr("ows_Title");
          var listportal=parseFloat($(this).attr("ows_portal"));
        data.addRow(["'"+ listtitle +"'",listportal]);

      });
    }
  });
}   

      function drawChart() {
     GetMyData();
        var data = google.visualization(data);
        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities',
          is3D: true,
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script> 
<div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

I have placed the script in a Script Editor and the `<div>` in a Content Editor.

I'm lost here, can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this may help you

```
<html>  
<head>  
<script src="/sites/ABCD/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="/sites/ABCD/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

    <script type="text/javascript"  
          src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={  
            'modules':[{  
              'name':'visualization',  
              'version':'1',  
              'packages':['corechart']  
            }]  
          }"></script>  

    <script type="text/javascript">  
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);  
      function drawChart() {  
            var SalesData = GetMySalesData();  
            var optionsSalesData   = {  
            title: 'Number of sales',  
            vAxis: {  
                    viewWindow: {min: -1},  
                    title: "Number of Incidents",  
                    displayAnnotations: true  
                    },  
             hAxis: {  
                    title: "Years"                
            },  
            pointSize: 5,  

            legend: { position: 'right' }  
            };  

            var chartSales = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('SalesChart'));  
            chartSales.draw(SalesData, optionsSalesData);     
      }  

function  GetMySalesData()  
{  
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();  
    data.addColumn('string', 'Year');  
    data.addColumn('number', 'Swift');  
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});  
    data.addColumn('number', 'I 20');  
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});  
    data.addColumn('number', 'Skoda Rapid');  
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});  



    $().SPServices({  
    operation: "GetListItems",  
    async: false,  
    listName: "Sales",  
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Swift' /><FieldRef Name='_x0049_20' /><FieldRef Name='Skoda_x0020_Rapid' /></ViewFields>",  
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {  
    var itemCount = $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName=rs:data]").attr("ItemCount");  
    alert('itemCount - ' + itemCount );  
    var count = 0;  
      $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName='z:row']").each(function()   
      {  
        count = count + 1;   
        var Year =  $(this).attr("ows_Title");  
        var SwiftSalesCount =  $(this).attr("ows_Swift");  
        var I20SalesCount =  $(this).attr("ows__x0049_20");  
        alert (I20SalesCount);  
        var SkodaSalesCount =  $(this).attr("ows_Skoda_x0020_Rapid");  
        data.addRow(["'"+ Year +"'", parseFloat(SwiftSalesCount),"'"+parseFloat(SwiftSalesCount)+"'", parseFloat(I20SalesCount),"'"+parseFloat(I20SalesCount)+"'",parseFloat(SkodaSalesCount),"'"+parseFloat(SkodaSalesCount)+"'"]);  

      });  
    }  
  });  
return  data;  
}  


    </script>  
  </head>  
  <body>  

  <div>  
    <div id="SalesChart" style="width:700px;height: 500px;float:left ;margin:0 auto;display:block"></div>  

</div>  

  </body>  
</html>
```

Source: [Display SharePoint List Data in Charts Using Google API and SharePoint Services](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/313769/display-sharepoint-list-data-in-charts-using-google-api-and/)

Comment: i tried even this no use i still can't see the chart

Comment: i tried this again:

Comment: please check console if it shows any error

Comment: yes in console i'm getting this error: Object doesn't support property or method 'SPServices'

Comment: can you please check "jquery.SPServices" script is added on page ?

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Shared Documents/jquery.SPServices-2014.01.min.js"></script>

Comment: yes i have this : /scripts/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>

Comment: can you please change your script reference to below references and recheck functionality ? because mine is working perfectly.
also check if there is double reference in same page.

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.7.1a/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I also tried in my environment, doesn't work either. Any updates?